# Storing CSV file when running PowerShell with Intune

Tags: powershell, csv, import, intune

What are some options to save the CSV file when running the PowerShell script (imports the CSV) with Microsoft Endpoint with Intune?

Ways to save the CSV file outside of the cloud world

Comment: [`Export-Csv` is an option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: You can code sending files via sftp/scp.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you're trying to do? Do you want to write to (or read from) a csv stored on the endpoint, or read/write from a central location?